# VS2010 .NET Memory Analysis - extremely slow

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, memory-management, profiler

Running VS2010's .NET Memory Allocation analysis takes ages to complete.

The program itself ran for about 3 minutes and generated 35GB of memory allocations. The profiler's output file is about 28GB. The report analysis process took over **three hours** (on a dual Xeon with 8GB RAM) to complete.

This has happened to me every time I've run the memory profiler.
Is this your experience also with this tool?
Is there anything to do to speed up this process?

Thanks!

Comment: Having the same problem in Visual Studio 2012 RTM as well.

Comment: It's very slow on VS 2010 Ultimate for me.

Comment: I haven't tried running it myself but have you tried finding the bottleneck(s) with Process Explorer?

Comment: Dont a solution for your problem , but what we do is use Regate Memory Profiler instead for managed components.

Comment: I don't know about any solutions to speed up analysis, but after you will open it - you can save report as a VSPS file, so next time when you will need to open it - it will be much faster.

Comment: That's just the way it is -- churning through 28GB of flat files just takes some time. RedGate is faster, but the UI is unusable. Wait, you ARE doing this on a SSD, right?

Comment: Noticed the same thing with our main app under VS2010 and VS2012.  I could not justify letting the system spend half the day analyzing a performance report when I had development to do.  (I once let it run overnight analyzing less than 1/2 hr session and it still was not done the next morning.)  The "cpu sampling" was the only built in "profiling" tool that seemed practical enough for normal use.  (Would love to hear of any special tricks to get around that.)

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the amount of RAM available to VS2010 by using the following link, you can also use it in VS 2012 and it really does makes a difference to performance (especially build times on large projects). Hopefully this will also help you with memory allocation analysis:

http://forthosewhomatters.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/largeaddressaware-and-visual-studio.html

Comment: @AlexandreBrisebois Yes it does :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but did not really find a solution for it.
If you need the profiler on a regular basis it might be worth looking at commercial ones. Here is a [list](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/5-good-and-useful-net) of other ones. I think all of them are available as trial version.

There are also many [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) posts on StackOverflow.

Good Luck, Stephan