# Track what objects are using my memory in c# app?

Tags: c#-4.0

I've got a c# app that uses a large amount of memory. I'd like to track down what objects are using the most memory so that I can optimize things a little more. Is there a tool that can help out with this? Something that would allow me to know what objects/variables/etc are using ram and how much?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers but I am not certain if there is another way for you to get this information outside of using a profiler.  I can't think of another approach.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at what I did with VS2010, you may have the `Analyze` menu.  If so, then you can use this to get some information that may help.

But, as this question pointed out, it is slow, and generates huge files.
[VS2010 .NET Memory Analysis - extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055232/vs2010-net-memory-analysis-extremely-slow)

So, you will want to look at the various options and try the one that will best help you find just what you want.